# Searching for picture book about a tiger that can move in and out of paintings

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

When he was about five years old, my brother got a picture book about a tiger that emerges from its jungle painting to hunt.  He has some adventures then returned to the art gallery where his painting was hung.  At that point, he has a great deal of trouble of locating his own painting.

The book's pictures featured a bunch of interesting paintings.  I'm not sure whether they were real famous paintings or merely pastiches of famous artists.  The tiger jumps into several paintings in the search for his own home.  At one point, he jumps into the wrong jungle picture and then gets into an argument with a couple of monkeys in that picture.  At another point, he jumps into a Picasso to stay out sight of the security guard; he finds being twisted around by the cubist environment quite uncomfortable.

Does anybody know what this book was?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*A Painted Tale* by Kate Canning

Reviewer on Amazon says:

> Famous works of art included as the tiger prowls his painting and then
>   leaves to find food, befriending an old lady.

https://www.amazon.de/Painted-Tale-Kate-Canning/dp/0903767295

You can see the tiger in front of the Picasso painting in this Etsy listing:
https://www.etsy.com/in-en/listing/255503697/a-painted-tale-kate-canning-1979?show_sold_out_detail=1